# How to feed data to a schema inside an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, widget, dashboard

I am trying to write a custom directive that will "create" a dashboard widget including:

1. Title (the name of the widget)
2. Schema (the way the data should be modelled or shown, i.e. it could be the number of users registered - an number, or it could be a string displaying the day of the week with most users etc...)
3. Data (the data to feed to the schema, a number, a string, or whatever is fetched from the db or datasource)

Here is how far I got with my directive:

```
app.directive('widget', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        title: '@',
        schema: '&',
        data: '&'
    },
    template: '<div>' +
        '<span class="widget-title">{{title}}</span>' +
        '<div schema="schema()" data="data()"></div>' +
        '</div>'
}})
```

and my html:

```
<widget title="Number of users" options="numberWidget" data="userData">
</widget>
```

I am stuck on how to "bind" the data to the schema, and where I should define the different schemas (or widget models). Maybe my approach is wrong, so a little direction would be much appreciated. I can provide more info if needed.

**EDIT:** 
Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/wons88/pen/GmyzaW) i made of how far I am and what I thought I could achieve - maybe it can be (or should be) done differently.

Comment: what is schema() and data(). is it in the controller??. From my understanding you are just trying to bind an object from a view scope to directive scope. Is that it?

Comment: can you provide schema() and data() return sample. Its better to create a codePen for it (with static values).

Comment: I have added an example of how far I am with it, currently unfinished as I am stuck, hence me writing this question. Plz check my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I decided to do it slightly differently to what I though it worked. Here is my solution:

**Directive:**
The directive is restricted to an Element and has an isolated scope which takes some arguments, the data with `'&'`, which evaluates an expression (the expression is defined in the **controller** as a function shown below) and the classes and title with `'@'`, which evaluate a string (these strings are defined in the **HTML** shown below)

```
app.directive('widget', ['$log', function ($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '&',
            valueClass: '@',
            keyClass: '@',
            widgetTitle: '@',
            titleClass: '@'
        },
        template:
          '<div><span class="{{titleClass}}">{{widgetTitle}}</span></div>' +
          '<div><span class="{{valueClass}}">{{data().value}}</span></div>' +
          '<div><span class="{{keyClass}}"> {{data().key}}</span></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                    scope.data = newValue;
                    $log.info('updating data');
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
}]);
```

**HTML:**
The HTML then initializes the 'widget' element created from the directive like so:

```
<widget title-class="widget-title" 
        widget-title="Number of Users" 
        data="userData" 
        value-class="number-widget" 
        key-class="description">
</widget>
```

The data attribute calls a `$scope` variable from the controller

**Controller:**
The controller simply fetches the data required in this example, it is a dummy object defined on `$scope` called `$scope.userData`:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.userData = {
            key: 'Total Users',
            value: 100
        };
    }
]);
```

**CSS:**
The CSS obviously defines the classes used in the HTML element, this is down to preference of styling but just for my example I will show them:

```
.widget-title {
    //whatever you need
}

.number-widget {
    //whatever you need
}

.description {
    // whatever you need
}
```

I hope this helps someone, any maybe there's a better way of doing but this suited my needs.